# Does the proposed Aliyah.SE fit better here?

Tags: discussion, scope, area51

I just saw [the Aliyah.SE proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/34450/aliyah) and wondered why those questions wouldn't belong here.  One possibility is that not all those who make aliyah are religious (or Jewish) and maybe some would think they don't belong here.  On the other hand, we just had a challenge a couple weeks ago for questions on that topic.

Should we invite them to consider bringing their questions here?

Comment: This proposal has since been deleted.

Comment: @HodofHod, good catch.  Could you put that in an answer so I can accept it and close out this question?

Answer (score 8):

As its proposer is a current user of J.SE ([TalFishman](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/766/tal-fishman)), I assume he has decided that it would work well on its own.

Personally, I think that many of those questions would fit here, but many would not. "Will I need to buy a car if I will be living in Ra'anana?" is one of their example questions that I feel would not fit so well here.

---

Edit: This proposal has since been deleted, and so the question is now irrelevant.

Comment: +1. Actually I can envision many questions that would not fit here at all. The problem simply may be that there won't be too big of an audience for their proposal...

Answer (score 0):

The potential user base of people considering making Aliyah is, regrettably, quite small. But what about [Travel.SE](https://travel.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Nope. In their FAQ they write: "and it's not about ... how to immigrate to a specific country"

Comment: There's also an Immigration proposal (referenced on the Aliyah one).  I'd bet that's where they end up for reasons of viability.

Comment: @Monica - Oooh, that's a good point. Nice catch.